# Lua - C++ object metatable returns nil

Tags: c++, reflection, lua, metatable

I have just started delving into Lua, and I learnt that C++ object properties could be accessible through metatables.

I am trying to access such an object's functions in a game's script: "**GameLib**". It is available in Lua as a global variable, but *getmetatable()* returns nil:

```lua
-- example usage elsewhere in the scripts:
local pPlayer = GameLib.GetLocalPlayer();

-- my tried code:
local mt = getmetatable(GameLib);
print("Metatable type:" .. type(mt)); -- "Metatable type: nil"
```

What could be the problem? Are there cases, when a C++ object has no metatable? If so, is there another way to access its properties?

Comment: Function `getmetatable` might be redefined to deliberately hide metatables from you (except metatables created by you).

Comment: Are you sure `GameLib` isn't just a regular old table? What game are you using Lua in?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff How common is that, compared to just using `__metatable` (which won't let you return a nil)?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica You are right, it was indeed a table, where function names are the keys and - mostly - the C++ pointers are the entries. I didn't know that functions can be called directly without indexing or anything like that.

Thanks for the answers!

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica - Sometimes it is easier to redefine one function than insert additional field into 50 metatables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Lua 5.4 Reference Manual:

[2.4 Metatables and Metamethods:](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#2.4)

> Every value in Lua **can** have a metatable.

> By **default, a value has no metatable**, but the string library sets a metatable for the string type

So there are cases where values, even userdata have no metatable. In fact that's default.

[6.1 Basic Functions: getmetatable](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-getmetatable)

> If object does not have a metatable, returns nil. Otherwise, if the
> object's metatable has a __metatable field, returns the associated
> value. Otherwise, returns the metatable of the given object.

So the that leaves us with two options why `getmetatable(GameLib)` returns `nil`:

1. `GameLib` does not have a metatable
2. `getmetatable` is not Lua's `getmetatable`. It has been overwritten by a function that returns nil for at least some values. Trivial `function getmetatable() end`

Comment: Thanks for the elaborative answer! 

There was some confusion on my part as to how Lua handles structs that are usually objects in other business languages. C++ exported objects have the possibility to include their data in a metatable, which seemed exclusive; however the actual object representations can be of the type Lua table themselves, which I totally missed.